# Exclude HTML elements with specific selectors during web scrapping

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to scrappe datas from a website. I got my list of elements (.sc-bKKYHN.ejco) and i need to scrap text in each elements contained. But i need to exclude elements with selectors = sc-kfhTrB kljtAb sc-fLQJNu hDgdeC and selector = sc-bGKsmU JDqvt. I dit with the test block but it doesn't work...

```
const elements = await page.$$('.sc-bKKYHN.ejco');
      const texts = [];
      for (let element of elements) {
        const classes = await element.evaluate(el => el.getAttribute('class'));
        if (classes !== 'sc-kfhTrB kljtAb sc-fLQJNu hDgdeC') || (classes! == 'sc-bGKsmU JDqvt') {
        const text = await element.evaluate(el => el.innerText.replace(/\n/g, '/'));
        texts.push(text);
        }
      }
      const valuesString = texts.join('/');
```

Different ways to do this but still doesn't work

Comment: When i say it doesn't work, it means that the two selectors exception are still scrapped

Comment: And i also forgot to say that the two selector exception are not directly under the element .sc-bKKYHN.ejco

Comment: Can you share the site or markup as a [mcve]? It's hard to debug something that can't be seen. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a web browser emulator like [jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom) to parse the webpage allowing you to use standard `document.querySelectorAll()` to find what you want.

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
dom.window.document.querySelector(...
```

Comment: I'm using puppeteer, does it work ?

Comment: I think so. I use jsdom. See `.querySelectorAll`

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove those from DOM first:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".sc-kfhTrB,.mkljtAb,.sc-fLQJNu,.hDgdeC,.sc-bGKsmU,.JDqvt")].map(el => el.remove())
})
```